# Incorrect formatting appearance - fixable?

Tags: bug, formatting

My first post on Meta & I didn't find anything similar by searching...
I see this a lot, on various question/answers - the last line of a code section hidden behind the scroll-bar...

[image]

If I check Edit, there is no fault with the user's formatting, they have added lines underneath [& incidentally if I then Cancel the formatting 'fixes' itself]

Is there a 'higher-up' who could have a look at this & fix it?

My System - Early 08 Mac Pro; 10.9.4, 26GB RAM, SSD, Safari 7.0.5

Link to this specific example - [Services menu shows the incorrect name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143649/services-menu-shows-the-incorrect-name)

Further testing - Chrome shows it just fine, Safari does if I refresh the page, but consistently fails on first opening of that link. I really have no special kind of setup in Safari, it's pretty much fresh out the box in terms of how I have it configured.

Comment: Can you link to the question so we can see the issue - it has probably something to do with your browser setup

Comment: Sure - wasn't sure I could find it again, but I did..

Comment: Looks OK on my Safari OSX 10.9.4

Comment: Hmm... it works if I simply click the link, fails if I Cmd/Shift/Click to open in new tab, which is my default method for forum browsing.

Comment: The latter i.e. right click is how I opened it

Comment: Stranger still - right click open in new tab fails, open in new window works.

Comment: Can but hope - it's not hugely irritating, tbh, I'll survive ;-)

Comment: works ok here with 7.0.5 and right-clicking to new tab. Maybe you've installed an extension which impacts rendering?

Comment: You appear to be correct - BOTH Click to Flash & YouTube5 do it, if either is enabled, I see the error, both disabled I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be fixed with OS 10.9.5 & Safari 7.0.6, even with Click to Flash & YouTube5 enabled.